# Problem with dpkg (interrupted)

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, dpkg

Yesterday I tried to install an app but for some reason it got interrupted. Today I tried to install another app but I got an error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'to correct the problem
```

after that when I type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get this:

```
Setting up mime-support (3.59ubuntu1)...
```

but suddenly my system freezes and my ram usage goes to 95%.

For solution I tried:

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get remove mime-support`

But nothing happens or it get stock.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What app were you trying to install? Check if it managed to install it because it sounds like it worked.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Comment: I think I was uninstalling Cario-dock... It's not in the menu anymore but I have it in the list of installed packages

Comment: here's the list http://www.mediafire.com/download/d8ws1fh9p1a8pbr/someFile.txt